# How to convert my ER diagram to sql?

Tags: mysql, erd

How can i convert my ER diagram to an SQL file in MySQL Workbench?

My ER diagram in MySQL Workbench already consists of tables, foreign keys etc, how can I convert it to MySQL script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a menu item to do this: **File** → **Export** → **Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script...**

Or, you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut - it is handy if you use the Forward Engineer often.